# Error while Running CI Pipeline on Gitlab

Tags: angular, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I am trying to deploy my angular 7 application on gitlab,my .gitlabci.yml contents are as below
its giving on pipeline and both jobs are failing.
I want to run tests on CI

```
image: node:latest

cache:
  key: ${CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG}
  paths:
    - node_modules/

before_script:
  - apt-get update && apt-get install -y unzip fontconfig locales gconf-service libasound2 libatk1.0-0 libc6 libcairo2 libcups2 libdbus-1-3 libexpat1 libfontconfig1 libgcc1 libgconf-2-4 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 libglib2.0-0 libgtk-3-0 libnspr4 libpango-1.0-0 libpangocairo-1.0-0 libstdc++6 libx11-6 libx11-xcb1 libxcb1 libxcomposite1 libxcursor1 libxdamage1 libxext6 libxfixes3 libxi6 libxrandr2 libxrender1 libxss1 libxtst6 ca-certificates fonts-liberation libappindicator1 libnss3 lsb-release xdg-utils wget
  - npm install --silent

stages:
  - test
  - build

job 1:
  stage: test
  script: node_modules/.bin/ng test

job 2:
  stage: test
  script: node_modules/.bin/ng e2e

release_job:
  stage: build
  script: node_modules/.bin/ng build --prod --aot
  artifacts:
    name: "project-$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME"
    paths:
      - dist/
  only:
    - tags
```

Getting error:
[image: Pipeline Error]

Comment: Usually with CI pipelines, you would use npm scripts to run Angular CLI test/e2e/build commands. See if changing your test script to `npm run test` works. The e2e script may need to be `npm run e2e`.

Comment: Not sure about your issue. But I will advise you to **not** use the latest version of a docker image in a CI pipeline. You can always upgrade at any point, and so could they and break your pipeline. Your versioned software should build today and tomorrow if you are to get real benefits from continuous integration.

Comment: @mohit if my answer fixed your problem, please mark it as the correct answer to help others. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I don't know what is in your node_modules so it is hard to say. (In future, I recommend posting that information)
My first suggestion would be to ensure you have the Angular cli in your node_modules. It should be in your dev dependencies of your `package.json` .

Otherwise I'd suggest using the Angular cli globally and install it as a separate entity.

If you install it globally, your Gitlab CI instance will be able to find it when you use `ng` instead of using `node_modules/.bin/ng`

Add this command along side / inside your installation stage before you use any `ng` command. (The -g means globally).

> npm i -g @angular/cli

Then you can run `ng test` etc. instead of referencing node_modules.

Comment: Thanks..this solved above error..but another poped up  No binary for Chrome browser on your platform.
  Please, set "CHROME_BIN" env variable.

Comment: That's a different problem. I'd separate that from this. Or this question will be about multiple queries and that isn't how stack overflow works. I've seen a resolution to that on stack overflow before. Have a search :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52092596/chromeheadless-giving-timeout-when-running-gitlab-ci-pipeline-with-docker-centos this could help